# Write output to multiple tables from REDUCER

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

Can I write output to multiple tables in HBase from my reducer? I went through different blog posts, but ma not able to find a way, even using `MultiTableOutputFormat`.

I referred to this : [Write to multiple tables in HBASE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11039668/write-to-multiple-tables-in-hbase)

But not able to figure out the API signature for `context.write` call.

Reducer  code:

```
public class MyReducer extends TableReducer<Text, Result, Put> {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger( MyReducer.class );

    @SuppressWarnings( "deprecation" )
    @Override
    protected void reduce( Text key, Iterable<Result> data, Context context ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        logger.info( "Working on ---> " + key.toString() );
        for ( Result res : data ) {
            Put put = new Put( res.getRow() );
            KeyValue[] raw = res.raw();
            for ( KeyValue kv : raw ) {
                put.add( kv );
            }

            context.write( obj, put );
            **// I dont know how to give table name here.**

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To identify the table names you should pass the table name as the key to `context.write(key, put)` method:

```
ImmutableBytesWritable key = new ImmutableBytesWritable(Bytes.toBytes("tableName"));
context.write(key, put);
```

But if you want to load a huge amount of data via MapReduce job at once then it might be interesting for you to use `MultiTableHFileOutputFormat`. This   output format creates HFiles for every HBase table you need and then you can easily load these files with `LoadIncrementalHFiles` tool:

```
hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles /tmp/multiTableJobResult hbaseTable
```

You can read more about `MultiTableHFileOutputFormat` in the article: http://tech.adroll.com/blog/data/2014/07/15/multi-table-bulk-import.html

Comment: Yes that is right(+1)  we have to pass table as key through above said way. if you are writing through mapper then  below mentioned is the way.       // rowKey is the hbase rowKey generated from lineBytes
  Put put = new Put(rowKey);
  // Create your KeyValue object
  put.add(kv);
  context.write("actions", put); // write to the actions table