# Writing to multiple HBASE Tables, how do I use context.write(hkey, put)?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I am new to Hadoop MapReduce. I would like to perform multiple tables writes from my reducer function. Which will be something like, if anything is getting written to Table1 then I want the same content in table 2 also.

I have gone through the posts like [Write to multiple tables in HBASE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11039668/write-to-multiple-tables-in-hbase) and checked the "MultiTableOutputFormat". But what I don't understand there is that according to the post in reducer function I should just use

1. `context.write(new ImmutableBytesWritable(Bytes.toBytes("tableName1")),put1);`
2. `context.write(new ImmutableBytesWritable(Bytes.toBytes("tableName2")),put2);`

I don't understand that if we do this then where are we defining the row where we want to update the value. Like for example I saw some code snippets and saw them writing into the table as `context.write(hkey, put)`. Where I think `hkey` is not the table name instead it represents some particular row in the table.

How should I deal with this?

Comment: What are you putting in the `Put` parameter, thats where you would specify the key.

Comment: I think I overlooked that part. Thank you!!

Comment: context.write() is taking Text and Writable Value as the parameter. How should pass the table name now? Since I can't use the below mentioned command now:

`context.write(new ImmutableBytesWritable(Bytes.toBytes("tableName1")),put1);`